# South 'nothing to migrate' message after successful schema migration

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-south

I have a Django app that I added South to, performed some migrations with, and runs as expected on my local machine. However, I have had nothing but database errors after pushing my project to Heroku.

In trying to deal with one database error I am experiencing, I attempted a test where I deleted one of my models, pushed the edited models file to Heroku and ran:

```
heroku run python manage.py schemamigration django_app test_remove_pub --auto
```

This seemed to work fine. I got back the message:

```
Running `python manage.py schemamigration apricot_app test_remove_pub --auto` attached   
to terminal... up, run.6408
 - Deleted model django_app.Publication
 - Deleted M2M table for journalists on django_app.Publication
 - Deleted M2M table for tags on apricot_app.Publication
Created 0006_test_remove_pub.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py   
migrate django_app
```

So, South appeared to do everything I expected - it deleted my model and its many to many relationships and made the appropriate migration file. Next, I enter:

```
 heroku run python manage.py migrate django_app
```

And I get back:

```
Running `python manage.py migrate django_app` attached to terminal... up, run.4792  
Running migrations for django_app:
- Nothing to migrate.
- Loading initial data for django_app.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Why would it say "nothing to migrate" when obviously there are things to migrate??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you change the models, you need to do :

```
heroku run python manage.py schemamigration django_app --auto
```

if anything has changed

and then run

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate django_app
```

South applies migrations based on the entries in this database table: `south_migrationhistory`. So if you want to manually override it,

1. Remove all the entries with column `app_name` of the models you changed
2. Manually remove all the related tables. You can get a list of all the tables by typing this in the django shell:

   ```
   from django.db.models import get_app, get_models
   app = get_app(app_name)
   for model in get_models(app, include_auto_created=True):
       print model._meta.db_table
   ```
3. Remove the `migrations/` folder related to the app
4. Do a fresh migration: `./manage.py schemamigration app_name --initial`
5. Apply the migration `./manage.py migrate app_name`